# AJAX - JSON Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

When I am trying to receive data from the server side, error I am getting:

> 06-30 11:23:57.119: I/chromium(7486): [INFO:CONSOLE(50)] "{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (50)

JS file:

```
$j.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'http://www.myrandomurl.com/SupportData/login.php', 
    crossDomain: true,
    data:  {email: e, password :p},
    dataType: 'json', 
    async: false,
    success: function (response){ 
        //alert ("response");
        //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));    
        if (response.success) { 
            myApp.alert("you're logged in");
            //window.localStorage["email"] = e;
            //window.localStorage["password"] = p; 
            console.log(window.localStorage["email"]);                          
            //localStorage.removeItem('email');
            mainView.router.loadPage('main.html');                      
        } else {
            myApp.alert("Your login failed");
            //window.location("main.html");
        }
    },
    error: function(error){                                                 
        //alert(response.success);
        //myApp.alert('Could not connect to the database' + error);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        //window.location = "index.html";                       
    }
});
```

PHP side:

```
$sql = "SELECT login_id, email_id, password FROM login WHERE email_id='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($num_rows == 1) {
    $response['success'] = true;
}else {
    $response['success'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: As you can see in `console` you're getting `404` that means your URL is incorrect

Comment: I can access url directly, I get `{"success":false}` on direct access